# Renderizar solo 3 últimos elementos de un array que traje desde una api en Reactjs

Tags: array, reactjs, api

Estoy creando una aplicación con Reactjs consumiendo una api de n datos, para lo cual solo quiero renderizar los 3 últimos elementos del array de objetos y cada vez que en la api se agregue un nuevo elemento en el render se muestre

```
    [
      {...}, // first element
      {...}, // second element
        .
        .
      {
        "id": 50,
        "title": "notice 50 ",
        "description": "lorem lorem lorem",
        "date": "2021-02-15",
        "image": {
                    "id": 88,
                    "url": "/uploads/institucion_819747f43c.jpg",
                    "created_at": "2021-02-15T22:25:37.000Z",
                  },
         "file": null,
      } // last element
    ]
```

función de llamada a la api:

```
    const Threecards = () => {
       const [threecard, setThreecard] = useState([])
       useEffect(() => {
          getThreecards()
       }, []);

       const getThreecards = async() =>{
          const apicard = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/noticias')
          const jsoncard = await apicard.json()
          setThreecard(jsoncard)
       }
    const card1 = threecard[threecard.length-1]
    const card2 = threecard[threecard.length-2]
    const card3 = threecard[threecard.length-3]
    return (
          <>{
             <div key={card1.id}>
                 <p>{card1.title}</p>
                 <img src={`http://localhost:1337${card1.image.url}`} alt="card"/>
             </div>
             <div key={card2.id}>
                 <p>{card2.title}</p>
                 <img src={`http://localhost:1337${card2.image.url}`} alt="card"/>
             </div>
             <div key={card3.id}>
                 <p>{card3.title}</p>
                 <img src={`http://localhost:1337${card3.image.url}`} alt="card"/>
             </div>
            }
          </>
       );
    }
```

me sale este error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)** puede servirte para obtener los elementos que necesitas, **comenzando desde índice 0**; pero como tú necesitas los últimos 3, simplemente podrías pasar el número negativo.

```
const aux = arreglo.slice(-3)
```

De esta forma obtiene los elementos, comenzando desde el final de tu arreglo

```js
const data = ['Vegeta', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Sasuke']

console.log(data.slice(-3))
```

Y en tu componente lo renderizas

```
{data.map(item => (
   // HTML
))}
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :D